# How can I connect to my Meteor production database using MongoLab remote connection or RockMongo?

Tags: meteor

The URL generated by "meteor mongo --url" only works for 1 minute, and I suspect these services need to reconnect later. I get the following error in MongoLab after a short while:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve. Do you simply want to connect to the meteor production database or do you want access it via MongoLab and if so, why?

Comment: I want to use a nice GUI tool to look at my data. I've settled on MongoHub for now, but it would be nice to be able to use RockMongo or MongoLab remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb process runs the original mongodb from 10gen, all meteor does with `meteor mongo --url` is gives you what it uses to connect to it in URI form.

You might want to check your server for other processes that might block the connection such as a firewall.

You haven't given much information about your setup but if you're accessing your meteor project on the usual port 3000 using `meteor run` use port 3002 to connect to it not 27107 as in the screenshot.

Comment: I think you're talking about the local DB, I want to know about the DB that's hosted by Meteor, when you deploy to Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

For your Meteor.com hosted apps you can simply use:

```
meteor mongo <your-meteor-app's-sub-domain>.meteor.com
```

Or if you have a domain (cname) setup to point at your meteor app, you can use that domain instead, and if you use a password to deploy, then you'll be asked to enter that.

Note: Meteor has developer accounts now, so authorisation will be through that.

Answer (score 0):

For your Meteor.com hosted apps you can simply use:

```
meteor mongo --url <your-meteor-app's-sub-domain>.meteor.com
```

it will give you an URL with the following format :

```
mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<server adress>:<port>/<database>
```

In Robomongo for example, you need to split the string and paste them in the appropriate fields.

However, you can use this URL only for one minute, after that the URL is not correct and you cannot connect.